# Find select tag with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, capybara, minitest

I am trying to find  a select tag using capybara in a system test. I have a couple of select tags in a page and i want some in readonly mode when the user is editing.
I have come accross other post but can't find anything useful, though i found these selectors like find_field, find_button and find_link. I am trying to do this:

assert_equal true, find_select('id').readonly?.

This isn't working. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: undefined method 'find_select'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybara doesn't have a `find_select` method, but it does have a `:select` selector type - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/2.15.1/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L358

The first parameter to `find` is the selector type (defaults to :css if omitted) so you can do what you want with

```
assert_equal true, find(:select, 'id').readonly?
```

Since that uses a non capybara provided assertion it has the downside of not using any waiting/retrying behavior.  If the status of the element is dynamically changing this can lead to timing issues and flaky tests. If that is happening on your page you will be better off using the `:field` selector type which provides a `readonly` filter - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/2.15.1/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L88 - and can also match select elements (The `:select` selector doesn't have a readonly filter because technically the select element doesn't support readonly - see below).

```
assert_selector :field, 'id', type: 'select', readonly: true
```

assuming you've loaded the capybara provided minitest assertions that could also be written as

```
assert_field 'id', type: 'select', readonly: true
```

or with the ':select' selector assertion and a filter block

```
assert_select('i') { |el| el.readonly? }
```

Note though, in HTML the select method doesn't actually support a readonly attribute, so if what you really want is to make sure the select element is disabled then you would do any of

```
assert_field 'id', type: 'select', disabled: true
assert_select 'id', disabled: true
```

etc.